# Passing context to sub-directory

Tags: go

I have a `Context` struct that is used for the Application Context. The `ConfigureRouter` function receives the context as a parameter and sets the global variable `c` so middleware in the same file can use it.

```
var c *core.Context

func ConfigureRouter(ctx *core.Context, router *httprouter.Router) {
    c = ctx //make context available in all middleware
    router.POST("/v1/tokens/create", token.Create) //using httprouter
}
```

The one route listed above calls `token.Create` ( from the token package which is a sub-directory) but it needs the context too.

```
//token/token.go
func Create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    //Help! I need the context to do things
}
```

How can I pass the context to the token package?

Comment: Thanks, so any suggestions on what SHOULD be done?

Comment: I should make clear that the `context` in this question is not a request context but instead an "application context" that stores database and cache connections amongst other things. I don't see the problem of passing this around to make it available elsewhere in the project. This is an old question though so I have removed the global variable `c` since I asked this.

Comment: I may have been mistaken about the immutable context. I thought you were using net/context, but I see your variable is called core.Context... so I don't really know what that does.

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't use a global, if you can avoid it. It's bad practice... and where it matters most often for singleton process like yours probably is, is in writing unit tests.

Comment: Yes I'm in the same camp as you regarding globals - this was an early setup and they're not in use now. Regarding the context, I use Gorilla for the request context, but the Context in the question stores values from a config file that a user can set. Therefore, other files need access to these settings so I have two Contexts - unorthodox perhaps but it gets the job done!

Comment: Ah, okay. Gorilla contexts are protected by a mutex, so there's no need to worry about their immutability. I had net/context on my brain yesterday when I looked up this question, so I inadvertently overlooked that detail. I've removed my above comment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine your Create function as a function that returns the handler function:

```
func Create(ctx *core.Context) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
        // Now you have the context to do things
    }
}
```

Where `httprouter.Handle` is a func type defined by httprouter to be `type Handle func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request, Params)`.

And then you would use it like this in `ConfigureRouter`:

```
func ConfigureRouter(ctx *core.Context, router *httprouter.Router) {
    router.POST("/v1/tokens/create", token.Create(ctx))
}
```